# CDI - inheritance: trigger producer of base type

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weld

I'm trying to implement some kind of producer factory pattern.
Is it somehow possible to trigger the producer method of a base type while injecting a derived type?

Assuming following interfaces:

```
interface Service
interface AService extends Service
```

I want to trigger this producer:

```
@Produces
Service factory()
```

At this injection point:

```
@Inject 
AService srv;
```

The purpose is to have one producer factory for different kinds of services by adding a marker interface (Service in this case).

Thanks for helping me

---

**Update:**

I tried LightGuards solution and added `@Typed` to the AService implementation:

```
@Typed(Service.class)
class AServiceImplemenation implements AService
```

Unfortunately I get an *unsatisfied dependencies* error. CDI does't invoke the `Service` producer for the `AService` injection point. Certainly, this make sense for typesafty reasons. But is there a way to force the invocation of the `Service` producer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a producer for the super type, and make it so that the AService type doesn't have a no args ctor (or one annotated with `@Inject`), or is `@Typed`, or `@Vetoed` in CDI 1.1 you could return any subclass of `Service` from your producer.

Comment: Unfortunately i got an _unsatisfied dependencies_
I marked the implemtation of AService with `@Typed(Service.class)`  
I also served a additional qualifier for the injection point and the producer. But i still get the _unsatisfied dependencies_

Comment: That's very weird. Which server? Are the classes all in the same war / jar?

Comment: I'm using jboss 7.1.1. All the classes are in one war.
The other way around (`@Inject Service` and a producer for AService) works fine. Where exactly should I place the `@Typed`?

Answer (score 0):

CDI does not allow producers to produce superclasses, it won't just find a suitable producer for your

```
@Inject 
AService srv;
```

I faced the same problem and my solution was:

```
public class ServiceProxy<T> {
    private final T service;
    public ServiceProxy(T service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    public T get() {
        return service;
    }
}

interface AService
//something

@Produces
@SomeQualifier
ServiceProxy factory(InjectionPoint ip) {
    Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType))ip.getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    //now we know actual service class and can produce one impl
}

@Inject
@SomeQualifier
ServiceProxy<AService> srv;
```